# Open-source linux alternative for Flash (as an animating tool)

Tags: linux, open-source, vector-graphics, animation

I am looking for an alternative for Adobe Flash.  In this situation, I mean it as an animating tool, *not* as a browser plugin.

I want a tool to make simple vector animations, and then, ideally, export them to animated SVG.

It can use, but doesn't have to use, Flash's logic and idioms. It *has* to run under Linux. Being free (as in freedom) is a huge plus.

(Unfortunately, "Flash alternatives" etc on Google just redirect me to various re-implementations of the browser plugin, I don't care about that now.)

Answer (score 1):

So far, I have found only [Synfig studio](http://www.synfig.org/cms/).

It seems to be a Free Software and having roughly the same capabilities as Flash, although with far worse GUI.

It has SVG import, it has no SVG export. There is a [tool, that exports to SVG](http://wiki.synfig.org/Sif2svg), but that tool produces SVGs where all the animated parts are off and it has a filter, that makes all the parts invisible.

However, I can "post-edit" the resulting animated SVG with Chromium Web Inspector (making animations in Chrome is the most weird and geeky possible thing, but it surprisingly works pretty well, just as CSS styling), so the animation actually does what it should do.

Answer (score 1):

As you previously stated [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/cms/) is a good option, but the UI is horrible and takes awhile to learn which is why I won't recommend it.

What I suggest is [Animatron](https://www.animatron.com/). Not It is a web application, but you can turn it into a desktop app (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and/or Chrome) using [WebDGap](http://webdgap.sourceforge.net/) if needed.

What's nice about [Animatron](https://www.animatron.com/) is it's very similar to Adobe Flash or [Edge Animate](https://www.adobe.com/products/edge-animate.html) for creating your animations. You can download as...

- HTML5 Code
- PNG
- SVG
- SVG SMIL Animation
- Video
- GIF

It works with events as well, plus you can [add in your own audio too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDl4jobXqfA)!

There's also [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but... 
Have a look at AnimationMaker.
I am developing this app as an alternative to Edge Animate.
It's running on Linux and Windows and produces mp4, avi, animated gif and also HTML.

https://artanidos.github.io/AnimationMaker/